# Remove unwanted object from image in android

Tags: opencv, image-processing, android

I want to develop an android app that has to remove unwanted object from an image.I have seen Exemplar Image Inpainting algorithm(Patch method) and opencv4 Image Inpainting.I am new to opencv4.I need some suggestion.If I am going in a correct way I need examples for using opencv4 Image Inpainting.if its wrong pls guide me.I have found 2 research papers based on this.

https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/168803/files/psivt_psa_paper_inpainting.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: `remove unwanted object from an image` seems to be very vague.

Comment: What kind of objects you want to remove from image? Can you show sample image.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.advasoft.touchretouch like this